# Unable to register a native Android app

Tags: android, facebook, registration

I am trying to register an iOS and an Android app that will post messages to the users' walls. I was able to register the iOS app. When I try to add the native Android app hash key to my app, Facebook registration page erases the hash and gives the following error:

Error
You have enabled a Native Android App integration for your app, but have not specified any Android settings.

I tried to register a separate Android app and that also gave me the same error. What is causing this error?

PS- The hash I used was the debug mode hash created as per the instructions on Facebook.

Comment: Register a general app, you may have set something exclusively for iOS, register general, you can post from iOS, Android and from web under the same name...

Comment: Yes, I did try to register a separate app as a native Android app. I got the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was just a problem with my browser. Some browser add on conflicted with the Facebook site. When I tried with a different browser, it worked.